# How to cite with only year inside brackets, and not the name?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I would like to cite with only the year within parentheses, however, the result is that both name and year come within parentheses.

E.g. **(Breusch, 1978)**, but I'd like this to be **Breusch (1978)**.

I have used the following code:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  backref=true,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  articlein=false,
  dashed=false,
  introcite=plain,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={red}}  

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bbx@introcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}
\renewcommand{\bibopenbracket}{(}
\renewcommand{\bibclosebracket}{)} % felicitaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
%\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad} omg finally, questa fa le parentisi è butto da vedere anche [] adiossssss

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareFieldFormat{linkallcite}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \bibhyperref{#1}%
}
\AtIntrocite{\DeclareFieldFormat{linkallcite}{#1}}

\letbibmacro{cite:orig}{cite}
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
  \printtext[linkallcite]{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:orig}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers    = {{et\,al\adddot}},
  backrefpage  = {zitiert auf Seite:},
  backrefpages = {zitiert auf Seiten:},
}



\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

Comment: `\textcite` should be what you're looking for …

Comment: Thank you so much it works!

Comment: You should definitely remove the `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` in your preamble. `natbib` and `biblatex` are completely incompatible and loading them in the same document will generate at least one incompatibility error message.

Comment: I really don't think you should have `\renewcommand{\bibopenbracket}{(}` and `\renewcommand{\bibclosebracket}{)}`. If you don't want square brackets in the introcite, change `\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}` to `\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibparens{#1}}`. Depending on what you want for `\cite` you may also have to change `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}` to `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}`. ...

Comment: ... Though I would probably just use `\autocite` (or `\parencite`) instead of `\cite` (which usually has no outer delimiters in author-year styles).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions.